# Fixed image within a div to make parallax scroll.

Tags: position, fixed

Okay. I have an issue with an image within a div. Fixed image within a div to make parallax scroll.
Here is what I want to do. 
I have a div. Here is code.

```
 #container{ 
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 100%; 
max-width: 1920px; 
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now I want to add an image in there that is fixed.

```
 #container-img{ 
position: absolute;
background-position:top center;
margin-right:0px;
bottom:0;   
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 100%; 
max-width: 1920px; 
display-inline: block;

 }
```

My problem is I want image fixed within the div and it goes all over the place. I do not want to add image via css as I have it in Wordpress for someone to change image when they want via dashboard. Here is HTML

```
 <div id="container" >
 <img id="container-img" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home.jpg"/>
 </div>
```

I want the css to make image fixed and not go outside the div? Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`display-inline: block;` is not a valid CSS. Try using `display: block`. Also `background-position:top center;` is not needed as you don't have any background image specified.

I would suggest you still use a background image with a `background-size: cover;` or you will have a hard time distorting the image proportions.

You will need to put the image in a inline style on your container:

`<div id="container" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home.jpg')">`

Hope that helps.